# Notation not recursive enough?

Tags: recursion, custom-notation

My notation is not recursing enough. For example,

```
Notation[W[a_ | b_] ⟹ foo[a_, b_]/foo[b_]]
Notation[W[a__, b_ | c_] ⟹ W[a__ | c_]W[b_ | c_]]
```

Then

```
W[a, b, c, d | e]
```

will give

```
foo[d, e]W[a, b, c | e]/foo[e]
```

My question is why does the `W[a, b, c | e]` in the above not expand further until it gets to the `foo` level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't recurse because you are using a definition of `Notation` (from the `` Notation` `` package) that *is restricted to parsing*:

[image]

This means that you will have to explicitly <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd> for the notation to take effect. Notice the following:

[image]

You can achieve what you want using straightforward definitions instead:

```
Clear@WW
WW[a__, Verbatim[Alternatives][b_, c_]] := WW[Sequence @@ Most[{a}], Last@{a} | c] WW[b | c]
WW[Verbatim[Alternatives][a_, b_]] := foo[a, b]/foo[b]
```

which gives as expected:

```
WW[a, b, c, d | e]
(* (foo[a, e] foo[b, e] foo[c, e] foo[d, e])/foo[e]^4 *)
```